# QMake OBJECTS issue after clean

Tags: qt, linker, qmake, object-files

I have a precompiled object file, say myObjectFile.o.  Inside my .pro file I have a block of code like this:

```
mac {
    ...
    OBJECTS += myObjectFile.o
}
```

This works great for linking in the object file with the rest of the project, but there is a fatal issue.  If I do a clean this object file gets deleted.  And since it's precompiled, when I try to build again I get a linking error until I copy the file back into my projects directory (I actually have a system call in my .pro file to copy the file so I just run qmake again).

This problem is annoying and causes some issues with our continuous integration server.  Basically, I'm looking for a way I can link precompiled object files into my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by adding the object files in `LIBS` rather than `OBJECTS`:

```
mac {
    ...
    LIBS += myObjectFile.o
}
```

The contents of `LIBS` are passed to the linker as-is, which makes it possible to include object files in it.